# Replace part of String resource with format string

Tags: android

Is there anyway to replace part of string resource with a format string.
For example: I have a story:
 "On your return trip from studying Saturn's rings, you hear a distress signal that seems to be coming from the surface of Mars. It's strange because there hasn't been a colony there in years. Even stranger, it's calling you by name: \"Help me, ***%1$s***, you're my only hope.\"",

This is stored in a string resource key.
I have an input ***username***, I want to replace the string ***%1$s*** above with this username. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have a resource

`R.string.template_string` as

```
On your return trip from studying Saturn's rings, you hear a distress signal that seems to be coming from the surface of Mars. It's strange because there hasn't been a colony there in years. Even stranger, it's calling you by name: \"Help me, %s, you're my only hope.\"
```

In code you can format this as

```
String username = "Bob"
String result = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.template_string), username);
```

### Warn:

You have incorrect template. Replace `%1$s` with `%s 1$`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is great for this question alone; however, I ask this question as the second part from my previous question, so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try test this code :

```
String.format(getString(R.string.desc), username)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, find the `EditText` that contains the username and format your string resource the following way:

```
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
String formattedString = String.format(
        getString(R.string.story), // your string resource
        username.getText().toString() // input from user
);
```